# jQuery: if XYZ, add class to this AND next element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an unordered list with an unknown amount of list items, in an unknown order.

I need to find the list items with a class of `.colspan`, see if the item after it also has that class, and then add a class depending on how many follow it.

If there's only 1 by itself, give that `li` another class `1-col`.

If there's two in a row, `2-col`.

If there's three in a row, `3-col`.

I don't need any more than 3 at a time.

e.g....

Before:

```
<ul>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

After:

```
<ul>
  <li class="colspan 1-col">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 2-col">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 2-col">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 3-col">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 3-col">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 3-col">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

I assume I use `.next()` in some way? And then, of course, `.addClass()`. That part I'm good with. It's the trying to figure out how to apply the `1-col`, `2-col`, `3-col` that's proving a challenge.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: BTW , you can't name a css class started with number . `1-col` should be `col-1` for instance .

Comment: Indeed, you are right. I wasn't thinking about that at the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to have a recursive function that counts up the number of next elements with the `colspan` class. Iterate over all `colspan`s, check to see if the `.prev` element is a `colspan`. If it is, then set the class name to the `-col` class of that previous element, otherwise call the recursive function with the current `colspan` (which will be the first one in any series of `colspan`s):

```js
const getCount = (elm) => {
  const next = elm.next();
  return next.hasClass('colspan')
  ? 1 + getCount(next)
  : 0
};
  
$('.colspan').each(function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  const $prev = $this.prev();
  $this.addClass(
    $prev.hasClass('colspan')
    ? $prev.attr('class').split(' ')[1]
    : 'col-' + (1 + getCount($this))
  )
});
console.log($('ul').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Interesting , I did it without recursion though .

Comment: This one is also very nice! It ONLY adds the class 1-col OR 2-col OR 3-col to the relevant elements instead of all 3 classes. How would I get it to say col-1, col-2, or col-3 instead of the other way around? (As pointed out that CSS doesn't like a class starting with a number). I had a play, but couldn't quite work it out.

Comment: @LeeLu Just change `1 + getCount($this) + '-col'` to `'col-' + (1 + getCount($this))`, see edit

Comment: You rule :) I'm marking this as the right answer for me! Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 3):

This would work (using nextUntil() makes it very concise):

```js
$(function(){
  $("li").each(function(index) {
    if($(this).hasClass("colspan") && !$(this).is('[class*="col-"]'))
    {
      var count = $(this).nextUntil(":not(.colspan)").length + 1;
      $(this).addClass("col-" + count);
      $(this).nextUntil(":not(.colspan)").addClass("col-" + count);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

It also is not limited in numbers of colspan it may encounter and doesn't use the example class "other" to match. (It matches on if it doesn't have colspan as a class).

Comment: This also incorrect , see the output : `class="colspan 3-col 2-col 1-col"`

Comment: No you are not. I think your solution is the best one so far .

Comment: Well I was for posting hastily without checking the results!
Thanks for the feedback though...

Comment: You are an absolute legend! Thank you :) Works beautifully. 
I did, however, change it around so that the class didn't start with a number. Thanks @Andre, I wasn't thinking about that aspect of it at the time!
It's now col-1,col-2,col-3 instead :)

Comment: Thanks LeeLu. (And @Ashraf for pointing it out) 
I've changed my code to match.

Comment: Also, note that if you value conciseness over readability, you could replace the last two lines with: `$(this).add($(this).nextUntil(":not(.colspan)")).addClass("col-" + count);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of your requirement. What i did is made a global variable and then checked for the class `colspan` and added the class dynamically

```js
let colspan = 1;
let other = 0;
$("ul li").each(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("colspan")){
    $(this).addClass(colspan+"-col");
    other+=1
  }
  else{
   if(other>0){colspan +=1}
   
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works only with the provided example , however it doesn't work with the following : `<li class="other">content</li><li class="colspan">content</li><li class="colspan">content</li> ...`

Comment: @Ashraf thanks, mate! i fixed it. Could you please verify?

Comment: still you didn't cover all cases , what about  `<li class="colspan">content</li><li class="colspan">content</li> .. `

Comment: @AshrafI believe its also covered

Comment: No . its not :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go .

```js
var skip=0;
var myUL = $('ul li');
myUL.each(function(index){
if(skip > 0) skip--;
else{
  if($(this).hasClass('colspan')){
    var i=index;
    var count=1;
    while(i<myUL.length){
      if(myUL.eq(i + 1).hasClass('colspan')){
        count++;
        i++;
      }
      else break;  
    }
    for(j=index;j<i+1;j++) myUL.eq(j).addClass(count+'-col');
    skip=i-index;
  }
}
})
console.log($('ul').html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any separator in your `colspan` LI like `other` class LI, then check it and You can do this by using `prevUntil` and `nextUntil`:

```js
$('ul li').each(function (k, v) {
var that = $(this);
if (that.hasClass('other')) {
 var u = that.prevUntil('.other');
 u.addClass(u.length + '-col');
 var u = that.nextUntil('.other');
 u.addClass(u.length + '-col');
}
});

console.log($('ul').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li class="colspan">content</li>
 <li class="other">content</li>
 <li class="colspan">content</li>
 <li class="colspan">content</li>
 <li class="other">content</li>
 <li class="colspan">content</li>
 <li class="colspan">content</li>
 <li class="colspan">content</li>
 <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

Without `prevUntil` and `nextUntil`

```
var i = 1;
$('ul li').each(function (k, v) {
 var that = $(this);
 if (that.hasClass('colspan')) {
  that.addClass(i + '-col');
 } else {
  i++;
 }    
});
```

Comment: What if there wasn't any `hasClass('other')` li ? this will never work .

Answer (score 0):

First, a valid CSS class name can't start with number. Thus I'll use postfix them i.e. `col-1`

Non-jQuery solution:
https://plnkr.co/edit/HXfeTJVFlbYI5C2om79l?p=preview

```
let group = []

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
  if (li && Array.from(li.classList).includes('colspan')) {
    group.push(li)
  }
  else {
    group = []
  }

  group.forEach(element => {
    element.classList.add('col-' + group.length)
  })
})
```

If you want to update class list only when necessary:

```
let group = []
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('li')

lis.forEach((li, index) => {
  if (index === lis.length - 1) {
    group.push(li)
  }

  if (li && Array.from(li.classList).includes('colspan') && index < lis.length - 1) {
    group.push(li)
  }
  else {
    group.forEach(element => {
      element.classList.add('col-' + group.length)
    })
    group = []
  }
})
```

Comment: Just Inspect the resulting HTML - it's wrong. eg `colspan col1 col2 col3`

Comment: A valid CSS class name can't start with number. It's just a matter of adjusting string. What's important here is the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
 var clmn = 1; /*Define global variable */
 $( "li" ).each(function( index ) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('colspan')) {
          $(this).addClass(clmn  +'-col');
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('other')) {
          clmn =  parseInt(clmn) + 1 ;
      }
 });
```

Comment: Incorrect also for the case `<li class="colspan">content</li><li class="colspan">content</li> ..`

Comment: what you need actually:

In my case script output will be
<ul>
  <li class="colspan 1-col">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 2-col">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 2-col">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 3-col">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 3-col">content</li>
  <li class="colspan 3-col">content</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>

Comment: I'm suggesting you to check the case provided above by me , then your code will result an incorrect output .

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve the problem:

```js
var col = 0; // Col variable initial value

// Loop through all li elements
var el = jQuery("li").each(function(e) {

  var _this = jQuery(this);

  // If "other" class found then add col-# to all previous elements until reaching "other" class again
  if (_this.hasClass("other")) {

    _this.prevUntil(".other").addClass("col-" + col).text(_this.text() + " col-" + col);

    // reset col variable
    col = 0;
  }

  // Increase only if we have colspan li element
  if (_this.hasClass("colspan"))
    col++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
  <li class="colspan">content - colspan</li>
  <li class="other">content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if there was no `class="other"` !

Comment: @Ashraf is correct: there is no class="other", that was there just to show you that it could be something else!